# Zend redirect to controller action with parameter

Tags: zend-framework

How I can redirect from one action on controller to another action
on different controller with parameter?

I got number controller->number action to where I want go with one parameter,
from index controller->index action.

Answer (score 1):

```
$redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');

$redirector->gotoSimple(
    'action', // action to redirect to
    'controller', // controller to redirect to
    'default', // module
    array('param1' => 'test', 'param2' => 'test2') // params
);
```

Comment: Something is it right a got error like this:`Notice: Undefined property: CrudController::$_redirector in C:\xampp\htdocs\kdd\application\controllers\CrudController.php on line 23

Fatal error: Call to a member function gotoSimple() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\kdd\application\controllers\CrudController.php on line 23`

Comment: Sorry was an error in my example. $this->_redirectors has to be $redirector.

Comment: ok, it is works when to param I pass string but how I can pass $var. Something like:  `$redirector->gotoSimple(
    .......
    'default', // module
     array('number'=> $number ) // params
);` when I try pass like this a got error: Message: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'number',
  'action' => 'number',
  'number' => 
  array (
    0 => 'crud',
    1 => 'create',
    2 => '111111111',
    3 => 'default',
  ),
  'module' => 'default',
)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$params = array('user' => $user, 'mail' => $mail);


$this->_helper->redirector($action, $controller, $module, $params);
```